# Can Starfleet personnel be fired?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, starfleet-command

In "The Apple", Kirk threatens to *"fire"* Scotty. Does that mean that within the early days of Starfleet that being 'court-martialled' was only a term for being brought before the "big boss" or Human Resources.

Can Starfleet officers and crewmen simply be dismissed?

Comment: Welcome! I don't understand your question - the title is clear but I don't get the rest eg what does it have to do with Starfleet being a nickname or not?

Comment: I don not understand the question either except for the title, but at least Spock has turned himself in to be court court-martialed in "The Menagerie", so, yes for the title. You want to know if Starfleet is a military organization, is that the question ?

Comment: Are you sure Kirk wasn't just trying to explain things to Capt. Christopher in terms he could understand, or just trying to cloud things over so Christopher wouldn't have all of future information? It's been a while since I've seen this episode.

Comment: The question is simple, it's starfleet a military like organization, or a corporate organization. Nasa is a corporate like organization for example

Comment: Edited to make the question less dupey and focus on your main point

Comment: Spock was fired at the end of Wrath of Khan, does that count?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs: too soon, man. too soon.

Answer (score 10):

In "The Apple" Kirk is clearly making a joke. If Scotty doesn't get the engines going he'll be **dead** in a few hours. Being fired is the least of his troubles!

As has been pointed out before, although Starfleet [isn't a military organisation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/54168/20774) per se, they do have many of the same trappings including a robust [court martial](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Court_martial) system so his being 'fired' (in the sense of summarily dismissing him) doesn't appear to be a *real* option available to Kirk.

Comment: A court *martial* is by definition military otherwise it's just ummm a court. What you are really seeing here is that the writers don't really understand what they're on about.

Comment: @gaius - It's perfect possible to have the "*trappings*" (e.g customs and procedures) of a military organisation (including referring to your internal discipline procedure as a court martial) without actually being a military force q.v - The Salvation Army.

Comment: *Court Martial* == "Military Court".  Despite on-screen dialog to the contrary, Starfleet is best describe as military even though their primary function is not warfare.  It has ranks, chain of command, court martial, etc. *AND* in a pinch they serve as military to fight wars too.  In every regard other than how they define themselves they **ARE** military.  Also consider that even current era militarys are not exclusively for war fighting.

Comment: @jimb - As has been pointed out (exhaustively) on the linked question above, Starfleet is not a military organisation. Picard said so, Roddenberry said so. What more do you need?

Comment: @Richard: Sorry, I tend to agree Jim2B.   Starfleet is a military organization even if it says it isn't.   The power of defining canon doesn't allow the redefinition of plain English words out of universe.

Comment: If it quacks like a duck... a rose by any other name...

Comment: @cde - So is the Salvation Army a military organisation in your book? It has military style ranks, promotion, even  "court martials" for wayward members..

Comment: When the salvation army starts running around with guns, ships, and weapons of mass destruction at the pleasure of the government,  sure.

Comment: What you are actually seeing is a disagreement between Gene Roddenberry, who said fairly frequently that Starfleet was not a military organization, and the rest of the show-runners after him, who basically ignored him.

Comment: Starfleet ships and crews are able to hold their own in stand-up fights against purpose-built warships and full-time warriors of other, tech-equivalent  civilizations. They may have other duties too but the *do* fulfill a military role, this is shown many times.

Comment: Then again, Kirk basically just "fires" Scotty in Star Trek Into Darkness, so...

Comment: @Omegacron -Spock literally fires Kirk (out of the ship)

Comment: Well, fired is exactly what's going to happen when the Enterprise burns up.

Answer (score 8):

Star Trek has shown a progression of Star Fleet through the series. Enterprise shows a very Nasa like component, While TOS is slightly more formal navy, and TNG era is strictly military format, even if they won't say it straight out. They have enlisted personal and commissioned officers. And they have their entire disciplinary process modeled after military tradition.

This includes marks on service records, demotions in rank, court martials, and finally discharges.

An example of a court martial is scene in the TNG episode Drum head, the meaning of which is a field court martial. And in one of the TOS movies, where Admiral Kirk is being court marshalled for his actions, and ***punished*** with a demotion to captain. An example of dishonorable discharge is seen in Voyager with Tom Paris.

Obviously Kirk meant fired in dark humor, making light of a dangerous situation as he always does (not mockingly or sarcastic, just a light hearted half joke).

Comment: And then in DS9, they are actually fighting a war for a significant portion of the series.  This is particularly obvious in "The Siege of AR-558," but runs throughout the later seasons in bits and pieces.

Comment: Drumhead never showed an actual court-martial. It was an investigative committee that had the power to lay down a court-martial as punishment. The actual court-martial would take place elsewhere off-screen at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that the phrase was clearly used in a joking way (what court would convict someone for not being able to break a ship out out of a tractor beam?), a court-martial isn't necessary to remove someone from their position.

Under [Article 15](http://usmilitary.about.com/od/justicelawlegislation/l/blucmj15.htm) of the Uniform Code of Military Justice, a superior is allowed to demote those under hir command or suspend them from duty entirely as well as dole out other extrajudicial punishments for minor offenses. As Starfleet is organizationally modeled partly after the U.S. Navy, it makes sense that Kirk would also have similar authority to discipline his crew and demote personnel without a court-martial.

Likewise, a summary court-martial for minor offenses can also be conducted by any officer with immediate jurisdiction over the person being tried. So Kirk could perform a summary court-martial by himself without involving anyone else.

Comment: Article 15 is as you said basically for minor offenses with single rank demotions and punishments of less than 30 days. Ops asking about firing/discharges which wouldn't be under article 15

Comment: @cde: I took the phrase as meaning "You're fired as Chief Engineer," which a demotion would essentially be, rather than kicking him out of Starfleet. Alternatively, he could have him "fired" from the Enterprise itself by kicking him off the crew altogether.

Answer (score -2):

Given the number of times we saw someone do something that waranted incarceration or firing, but the person wasn't, I'm going to say no. The following people did things that should have resulted in them being fired, but weren't.

- Leah Brahms: She designed the Enterprise D propulsion systems. The nacelles of the Enterprise will blow up the entire ship if they encounter a low speed collision. That's criminally incompetent design work, and she ought to have been fired. https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leah_Brahms https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode)
- Ben Sisko poisoned a inhabited planet as a gambit to arrest a thief. I'd fire a person for committing such a felony. uhttps://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/For_the_Uniform_(episode)
- T'Pol "Yes, she was a field recruit, but she counts", should have been fired for stealing starfleet property, and getting high on the job. I would fire an employee for either of these things. https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/T%27Pol https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Damage_(episode)

I've skipped the Voyager ones, because firing someone just wasn't practical there.

Comment: The Ben Sisko one is debatable, even within the episode. The poison would only make the planet uninhabitable to humans, and the only humans there had no claim to the planet.

Comment: None of those people were _tried_ for their actions, and court-martials do definitely happen in Starfleet. So you're just demonstrating Starfleet's low professional standards or cronyism.