# Has the Star Trek away team ever beamed down to a planet with significantly higher or lower gravity than Earth?

Tags: star-trek

Every episode I’ve ever seen has the away team walking around like they’re on Earth (for obvious out of Universe reasons). Are there any episodes where the actors pretend it’s difficult to walk around due to higher than Earth gravity or hop around with ease due to lower than Earth gravity?

Comment: not a planet, but in Star Trek VI, Enterprise crew beam to the Klingon ship which is without artificial gravity and are wearing magnetic boots. Exo III (TOS: What Are Little Girls Made Of?) had 1.1g

Comment: "*SPOCK: Ship's record banks show little we don't already know about this planet, Captain. Gravity is **one point one of Earth**, atmosphere within safety limits.*" - http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/10.htm

Comment: In Enterprise (Breaking the Ice) they take a shuttle to a comet. It's got lowered gravity, but obviously it's not a planet.

Comment: "for obvious in Universe reasons" Do you mean out of universe?

Comment: @Acccumulation - I’m new to the site and world of internet Star Trek Lingo. Is “in universe” real life or the show? I meant that the tv show is filmed in a studio/sound stage on Earth so gravity is the same as Earth.

Comment: Feel free to submit an edit if something needs to be clarified or I got my universes mixed up.

Comment: "in universe" refers to the fictional universe. That's not specific to the site or Star Trek: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in-universe

Comment: @Valorum Enterprise also had that one scene where the artificial gravity on the ship went on the fritz, leaving Archer floating in the shower.  (Yet another case of that show just being randomly gratuitous at times)  It's one of the only other times I recall them messing with gravity in the franchise.

Comment: @nkcampbell, may I ask if it's "done well" (as in The Expanse) or are they "merely pretending" (as in Batman scaling a skyscraper, hah)?

Comment: @NKCampbell Similarly, the spacewalk in Star Trek: First Contact

Comment: @Chronocidal Which part of that sequence involved the transporter?

Comment: The Star Trek Animated Series would have been the perfect opportunity to introduce something like this, but I don't know if they ever did.

Comment: I was about to answer "Xelayah", but then I remembered that The Orville is not Star Trek. :D Also, they used a shuttle instead of a transporter.

Comment: While not Star Trek, Stargate SG-1 had an interesting episode where a team gates to a planet in proximity of a stellar black hole. There are some unexpected gravitational consequences... https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/A_Matter_of_Time

Comment: @KlaymenDK Star Trek VI was well done in my opinion. If you want to see stellar pretending, you might want to check out Destination Moon. (Unlike Batman, Destination Moon was taking it seriously, but they had 1950 special effects.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Yes...and no.**

In [Amok Time](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/34.htm), Kirk, Spock, and McCoy beam down to Vulcan. None of the actors "pretend that it's difficult to walk around"; but other sources indicate that Vulcan has a higher gravity than Earth, as well as being hotter and having a thinner atmosphere.

[This discussion on TrekBBS](https://www.trekbbs.com/threads/i-thought-vulcan-was-supposed-to-be-a-high-g-planet.187972/#post-6951907) indicates that there is textual evidence that Vulcan's gravity is higher, where James Blish's story adaptation of the episode calls the shot McCoy gives Kirk a "high-G vitalizer shot". The Star Fleet Medical Reference Manual is also said to reference Vulcan as a high gravity planet.

As for canonicity: the Blish adaptations were commissioned by Bantam Books, who owned the license to publish Star Trek based fiction. He often went "off script" when writing, the above quote being an example.  The SFMRM is an official publication of Paramount Pictures.

**Conclusion:**

I think the best that can be said is that there is reasonably sound, relatively canonical basis for stating that Vulcan has a higher gravity than Earth, and that indeed a ST:TOS landing party went there and beamed down, though they did not pretend to be affected by the supposedly higher gravity.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it has the most number of votes, I think between all the comments and all answer a reader can get a generally complete answer to this question. Throughout the comments it was brought up that class M planets have gravity close to Earth. These planets will also have atmospheric pressure close to Earth.

Comment: If an away team were suddenly transported to a planet with significantly different atmospheric pressure than the ship, they may experience the bends or something similar. Even if an away team could survive for a short period of time on a planet with significantly different gravity the show usually just has them land on class M planets.

Answer (score 29):

I don't think we've seen a Starfleet away team beam down to a planet with dramatically higher or lower gravity than that of Earth. This is in part because they mostly beam down to [M-class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Class_M) planets, and one of the characteristics of M-class planets is that they usually have gravity similar to that of Earth.

There can be some variation though. In the Star Trek pilot episode, [The Cage](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Cage_(episode)), an away team beamed down to [Talos IV](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Talos_IV), which was stated by an unnamed officer to have gravity 0.9 that of Earth. Conversely, in TOS episode, [What Are Little Girls Made Of?](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What_Are_Little_Girls_Made_Of%3F_(episode)), an away team landed on [Exo III](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Exo_III), which was stated by Spock to have gravity 1.1 that of Earth. In neither instance did the away teams indicate that the gravity on those planets was noticeably different from what they were used to.

There apparently were some populated worlds in the Alpha Quadrant with gravity very different to that of Earth though. In the DS9 episode, [Melora](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Melora_(episode)), we were introduced to [Ensign Melora Pazlar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Melora_Pazlar), an [Elaysian](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Elaysian). As a result of growing up on the [Elaysian homeworld](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Elaysian_homeworld), a planet with gravity substantially lower than that of Earth, she found the artificial gravity on Deep Space Nine to be debilitating, to the point that she required a wheelchair to get around the station comfortably. We never really got to see the Elaysian homeworld itself though, aside from a photo which was likely taken there.

Comment: Would an M-class planet necessarily have similar gravity to Earth? The primary qualification is that the planet would be an appropriate distance from a Star . I may do some back of the envelope calculations on this. It would seem you simply need a planet in a habitual zone which isn’t directly related to planet size. My initial hunch would be a larger star would have a larger zone and have the possibility for a larger M-class planet. You did say “similar” so maybe there’s some correctness to that. I may look into it.

Comment: great reference to Melora. That's the closest example of the OP is actually looking for in terms of the effect of different planetary gravity on different species.

Comment: @NKCampbell - Thanks.

Comment: @Doug Small Berries - Memory Alpha's page on [gravity](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gravity) says: _"An M class planet was defined, in part, by having a gravity that is approximately equal to Earth's sea level."_ The ENT episode, _Fallen Hero_, is cited as a source. Admittedly, I rewatched this episode, and didn't notice any such statement being made. That's why I qualified my statement with the word "usually", because it is true to say that M-class planets visited by Starfleet away teams do _usually_ have gravity similar to that of Earth, even if it isn't a strict requirement.

Comment: @DougSmallBerries The gravity of a planet will also have an impact on atmospheric pressure, which might also be included in what makes a planet "Class M".  (Although, gravity isn't the only thing - Mars has 38% Earth's gravity, but less than 1% atmospheric pressure, due to the solar wind stripping gasses off into space)

Comment: If gravity is too much lower than Earth it won't hold an atmosphere.  If gravity is too much higher it will hold hydrogen/helium and you won't have a breathable atmosphere.

Comment: @Doug Small Berries there are limits to the size of an Earth planet which can be habitable to humans.  On the large side, the upper limit of surface gravity that humans could tolerate for longe rperiods would probable be about 1.25 or 1.50 that of Earth.  On the small size the escape velocity should be at least 5 times the root-mean-squae velocity of atomic oxygen at the planet's temperature to retain oxygen long enough.  See Habitable Planets for Man, stephen H. Dole,  1964.
 https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

Answer (score 12):

This did not involve any beaming down, but it does answer part of your question:

> Are there any episodes where the actors pretend it’s difficult to walk around due to higher than Earth gravity

Yes, kind-of. In [Learning Curve (VOY)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Learning_Curve_(episode)), crew members are seen panting after having completed multiple laps around the deck and Tuvok raising the artificial gravity on that deck by 10%. Do note however that the crew members are out of shape and Tuvok (as a former instructor) is basically trying to get their fitness level up with improvised physical education. So it's not clear how much panting would've been involved had the gravity not been changed, but it's strongly implied it was relevant here.

Answer (score 6):

You wouldn't notice if they did. Modern infantry carry 30% of their weight in equipment, and you don't see them finding it difficult to walk; Starfleet is a military organisation¹ and the personnel are supposed to be fit². So any M-class is going to be ok, if the away team carries their usual light equipment load and beaming around rather than yomping, it isn't really going to be worth mentioning anything up to maybe 40% more than Earth.

Gravity can vary a lot - 'significantly' higher gravity suggests the in-universe reason of being asphyxiated as you're too weak to lift the weight of your ribs or passing out as you can't pump blood to your head, but that would be at several times Earth gravity.  Significantly lower gravity implies that you don't have as much atmosphere, and so need to suit up or at least wear breathing apparatus; TOS don't tend to go to locations they need to wear suits.

1. in the sense that when at red alert, every crew member is expected to be able to fight, rather than having a separate military force within the crew for away teams, boarding or other kinetic actions.
2. not necessarily as fit as C20th infantry in terms of carrying packs for multiple days, but certainly fit enough not to be a liability in combat or away missions

Comment: @DougSmallBerries the definition used in Star Trek (at least according to Memory Alpha), is that it is capable of sustaining humanoid life. Too much gravity for humans means it fails that test.

Comment: It might be noticeable if they jumped, although sadly we don’t often see that either.

Comment: Starfleet is *not* a military organization, according to the Great Bird of the Galaxy: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54154/is-starfleet-a-military-or-civilian-organization

Comment: @NKCampbell All the evidence suggests they have all the aspects of a military organisation. There are plenty of real world military organisations which claim not to be, and only exist to protect and serve.

Comment: ok - but Gene said they weren't so... :)

Comment: @NKCampbell I know he said that, I suspect he meant that it in some narrower sense rather than in the wider 'having the characteristics of soldiers or armed forces' sense. The accepted answer illustrates the point by showing military personnel in peacekeeping roles and claiming that means they are not military.

Comment: There is zero evidence that star fleet (a franchise from the 1960ies) personnell train in any way like 21st century infantry. Not even Worf and his security gang. Certainly not medical and staff personnell.

Comment: Modern infantry carry 30% additional weight, and these merely "fit" people are supposed to just barely notice 1.4 times their (body weight + equipment)? That math doesn't work out, sorry. ;-) Go and load a large rucksack with water bottles.

Comment: @Karl I'm not as fit as starfleet personnel, so that experiment would have no value. For the short periods shown, with centuries of advances of healthcare and fitness, and the gravity medication mentioned in other replies, and the typical away team's very light clothing and equipment, I think you wouldn't notice the difference when watching them on TV.

Comment: OK, for you, 15%. ;-) That's a crate of beer, minus ~ two bottles.

Comment: @Karl do you think that people on TV shows going camping carrying backpacks are carrying the full weight or just empty padding? Do you notice any difference in how they move? Sure in real life *I* noticed when I had to carry my daughter back from the park when she hurt her leg ~25% my weight, but doesn't mean someone would tell the difference watching a TV show.

Answer (score 5):

They obviously did, but not to the extent that it bothers them. Exceptions being the zero-g or very close to it scenarios.

Because:

1. All M-class planets are somewhat close to Earth gravity. It's part of the definition!
2. Anything more than 0.5g and less than about 1.8g is handled with nonchalance by the very well-trained crew. As are any except the most extreme of temperature, humidity, and light levels. As Starfleet, they are trained to adapt and function in all sorts of environments.

and most importantly:

3. The ***convert-o-matic cameras*** used to record their shenanigans filter out all of the weird stuff, makes all aliens look like humans with a dab of face putty, and lip-synchs all alien languages through the Universal Translator.
   This very effective filter of course hides most of the actual differences of the alien planets from us, the viewers.

edit: about g-tolerances.
Those come from NASA studies about human kinematics.
Below about 0.5g, we bounce due to leg muscle trigger thresholds.
Above about 1.8g, we stumble due to insufficient elasticity in the achilles and other leg tendons.
One assumes that personnel will be trained to all gravities where their bodies function adequately.

Comment: *"Anything more than 0.5g and less than about 1.8g is handled with nonchalance by the very well-trained crew"* - [Citation needed]

Comment: I always did wonder about the lip-synching.

Comment: @Valorum It was always my impression that none of the star trek personnell was very, ahem, sensitive.

Comment: @MarvinKItfox  It seems to me that if the natives of a planet look like ordinary Earth humans without superdeveloped muschles and bones, the surface gravity should be less than about 1.25 to 1.50 times that of Earth, believed to be the upper limit for humans to tolerate for long periods such as living on the planet.  See Habitable Planets for Man, stephen H. Dole,  1964.
 https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

Comment: @M.A.golding but how much of that appearance is due to the convert-o-matic camera's anthropomorphic alteration algorithm? The one that makes all aliens look like humans with minimal facepaint?

Comment: ... I wonder if the different visuals of Klingons are also based on a new generation convert-o-matic cameras software ...

Comment: @MarvinKitfox This is off topic, but do you fly a Kitfox? Did you build it yourself?

As far as your answer, I'm aware of plenty of suspension of disbelief in the show. I'm surprised they never tried to film a scene like this though.

Comment: The Convert-O-Matic raises the question: did Worf actually transform into a monster in that one episode, or was the Convert-O-Matic just malfunctioning?

Comment: For that matter, the Convert-O-Matic would also explain the Jem'Hadar dislike for chairs...